# http(80) to https(443) ssl redirection not working in haproxy?

Tags: ssl-certificate, haproxy

I have posted a similar question in stackoverflow. But since this site is better suited for this question, I am reposting it here.I am trying to redirect all requests on port 80 to port 443 ie,redirecting http to https (ssl) using haproxy.I have already created the pem certification file by referring to this link http://fosshelp.blogspot.com/2016/11/how-to-create-pem-file-for-haproxy.html. I have made sure to Append PRIVATE KEY and CRT(self-signed certificate) to mydomain.pem.

mydomain.pem

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

haproxy.cfg

```
frontend http-in
    mode    http

    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/mydomain.pem
    http-request redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }

    acl path-employeeList              path_beg -i /employeeList    
    use_backend employeeList-backend   if path-employeeList


backend employeeList-backend
    mode    http

    option  httplog
    option  forwardfor

    http-request set-path /

    server  appserver1 134.209.18.237:5000
```

Currently I can access my app at http://134.209.18.237/. But when I hit https://134.209.18.237/ I get 503 Service Unavailable No server is available to handle this request.Why is the redirection to https not working?Plz help

Is there anything wrong with my pem certificate file or my haproxy.cfg??Is the certificate file invalid??

Answer (score 0):

You have no backend for `/`, only `/employeeList` so there's in fact no one to handle your request. 503 seems about right.

Comment: okay i changed /employeeList to /

Comment: i also removed http-request set-path / from the backend and now the app is  succesfully getting  redirected to https

Comment: but i am still confused? Can you explain me what was the problem with the previous configuration?

Comment: Take a request for `/`, look at your frontend configuration and tell me which backend you expect it will use.

Comment: okay lets say if /employeeList is an alias name for the portnumber 5000.How should i change my config if i want to access it at https://134.209.18.237/employeeList  ?

Comment: okay i found out the issue!! replacing the line  http-request set-path /  with reqrep  ^([^\ :]+)\ /employeeList/?(.*)$  \1\ /\2 in the backend solves the problem!!

Comment: But what  if i have multiple backends running on different ports ?(ie , multiple applications which has to be mapped through haproxy)

Comment: i cant use  path_beg -i / for the other backend right?